# .htaccess to pass 5 letter variable

Tags: .htaccess

i want to write .htaccess whcih pass 5 letters to the page as variable
those 5 letters are (small alphabets & numbers only)

For example if someone goto www.abc.com/etd01 i want to pass etd01 to www.abc.com/link.php?link=etd01

so i wrote

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ LinkCode.php?LinkCode=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ LinkCode.php?LinkCode=$1
```

it is working but if some open www.abc.com/dswdrd then also it is passing the variable.
what i want is if length is 5 they pass otherwise do nothing

is it possible??

no i have change my .htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ LinkCode.php?LinkCode=$1
```

but now when i place

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ LinkCode.php?LinkCode=$1
```

at the end of joomla .htaccess file it doesnt work

joomla .htaccess file is below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ LinkCode.php?LinkCode=$1

<Files ~ "\.vcf$">
ForceType text/x-vcard
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have `+`, which means **1 or more**. If you want 5 **exactly**, replace it by `{5}`.

2) You said you want "(small alphabets & numbers only)", but your template will ALSO match capital letters as well as minus `-` and underscore `_`. I have removed them from pattern to match your requirement.

3) I've also joined 2 rules into 1 (will handle URL with and without trailing slash).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{5})/?$ LinkCode.php?LinkCode=$1
```

Comment: ok it is working fine if .htaccess have only this code but when i add code to joomla .htaccess file it doesnt work can you please check and let me know line in there affection this code not to work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Joomla. All what you need is to put the rule in correct place. Place it in your joomla .htaccess just after `RewriteEngine On` line (if `RewriteBase` line is present, then after that line).